# PostgreSQL consumes 50% Disk I/O with just one COMMIT, how to fix it?

Tags: postgresql

Here's a top line from iotop report:

> 2949 be/4 postgres 528.00 K 35.33 M 54.09 % postgres: irkfm  ::1(40069) COMMIT

Some postgres process hungs with 50% Disk I/O but I can't understand what it does, because it doesn't expose any SQL information, only word COMMIT. Now to find what it really does?

`SELECT pg_cancel_backend(2949);` actually won't kill the process.

P.S. I see a lot of

> IRKT WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress

in PosgreSQL log, about 200 per minute. But also I can't locate from this log what causes this warning.

Comment: To _kill_ a backend, you need `pg_terminate_backend()`. `pg_cancel_backend()` will just _ask_ the backend "nicely" to cancel the current query if possible

Comment: If you don't understand what it does, why would you want to kill it?

Answer (score 0):

`COMMIT` commits a transaction started with `BEGIN TRANSACTION`. Everything that happens within that transaction needs to be persisted when executing `COMMIT`. So you need to look into the queries previously executed to know what's happening.